# How to access configuration xml files of remote HDFS cluster using Java API?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a namenode address(ip address and port) and but I don't know the location of configuration files (i.e.core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml,etc) on the local file system. I want to access configuration details.

I know that by doing following I can get the details,

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(file path of core-site.xml);
conf.addResource(file path of hdfs-site.xml);
```

it is working on my local machine where I know the file paths. But I dont know the location of files on remote machine.

Is there any way to access the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If the real question is how to run code in one cluster and access HDFS on another then you don't need to addResource core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml as most tutorials show.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    //conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    //conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
    //FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    String fromFileName = "hdfs://my.source.cluster/a/b/c";
    String toFileName = "hdfs://my.dest.cluster/d/e/f";
    FileSystem fromFs = FileSystem.get(new URI(fromFileName),conf);
    FileSystem toFs = FileSystem.get(new URI(toFileName),conf);
```